# Convert string and byte[] to file in JAVA

Tags: java, backend

I have an interface with this strings and bytes array

```
public interface EmailAttachment {

    String getFileName();
    String getFileVersion();
    byte[] getContent();
    String getType();

}
```

i want to put all of this in a file, in my class Service how could i called?:

```
    @Override
    public Boolean sendEmail(EmailAttachment attachment) {
        File file = new File( "HERE,I want to bring everything");
        uploadFile(file);
    }
```

If i use `attachment.getFileName(),attachment.getFileVersion(),attachment.getContent(),attachment.getType()` 
it brings me an error because the file needs a path

Comment: Can we see an example of how you're using this?

Comment: if `uploadFile` requires a file, then you have a problem. You don't have a file, you have the data as a `byte[]`.

Comment: can you give more information, would you like to create a local file with the EmailAttachment information.

Comment: @f1sh yeah , uploadFile needs a file, that's my question , how could convert the byte[] in a file.

Comment: You need to write the data to a (temporary) file. But i highly recommend that you change the `uploadFile` method. There is no need to divert the data to a file just so that the data can be read from there

Answer (score 1):

try this out create a File object with the file name and pass it on to FileOutputStream.

OutputStream accepts byte array to store it in file, once uploading done close the stream.

```
 String FILENAME = ""; 
 File file = new File(FILENAME); 

 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file); 

 // here you can write bytes to file using FileOutputStream
 os.write(bytes); 

 // Close the file 
 os.close();
```